# Java - Collecting consumer?

Tags: java, java-stream, functional-interface

Is there a functional way to first collect the elements of a stream and then immediately pass the collection to a consumer? In other words a construct that waits for the stream to end before applying a terminal operation on all stream elements as a collection instead of one by one?

For example, can you implement the following as a one-liner:

```java
Stream<Event> stream = // a stream of events
List<Event> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
doProcessEvents(list);
```

---

As a workaround, I can (ab)use [Collectors.collectingAndThen()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) together with a `Function` to achieve the result I am looking for:

```java
Function<List<Event>, Void> processingFunction = (list -> {
    doProcessEvents(list);
    return null;
});

Stream<Event> stream = // a stream of events
stream.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), processingFunction);
```

---

Other alternatives that I considered (but that do not work) is if the `collectingAndThen()` method had a `Consumer` as second argument, e.g. `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collector downstream, Consumer consumer)` or if the `Consumer` interface had a `finish()` method that was executed after the last element in the stream was consumed:

```java
class EventConsumer implements Consumer<Event> {
    private final List<Event> list = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void accept(Event ev) {
        events.add(ev);
    }

    public void finish() {
        doProcessEvents(events);
    }
}

// usage
Stream<Event> stream = // a stream of events
stream.forEach(new EventConsumer());
```

The problem with this approach is that the events would be saved in the internal list, but the `finish()` method will not be invoked. It works with a slight modification, but still no one-liner:

```java
Stream<Event> stream = // a stream of events
EventConsumer consumer = new EventConsumer()
stream.forEach(consumer);
consumer.finish();
```

Comment: I'm not aware of anything built-in. But you could attempt to implement your own `Collector`

Comment: Why do you prefer any of the other solutions over `doProcessEvents(stream.collect(Collectors.toList()))`? I don't think they add clarity or performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided a different approach. Instead of trying to shoehorn together a collector and a consumer, I created an interface

```java
interface StreamConsumer<T> {
   void consume(Stream<T> stream);
}
```

and refactored the code as

```java
void processEvents(StreamConsumer<Events> streamConsumer, Stream<Event> events) {
    streamConsumer.consume(events);
}
```

---

What is the purpose of this? Now, I can implement different kinds of consumers, some that relies on `List<Event>`, others that can consume `Stream<Event>`, e.g.

```
class ListEventConsumer implements StreamConsumer<Event> {

    private ListProcessor<Event> listProcessor;

    ListEventConsumer(ListProcessor<Event> listProcessor) {
       this.listProcessor = listProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    void consume(Stream<Event> events) {
        List<Event> list = events.collect(Collectors.toList());
        listProcess.process(list);
    }
}
```

as well as standard Java `Consumer` implementations, e.g.

```
class FunctionalEventConsumer implements StreamConsumer<Event> {

    private Consumer<Event> consumer;

    FunctionalEventConsumer(Consumer<Event> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    void consume(Stream<Event> events) {
        events.forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

Now, I have a way of consuming `Event` both as a `Stream<Event>` as well as first collecting them in `ListEventConsumer` class that delegates them to a `ListProcessor<Event>`. With this approach, the class that delegates the event processing does not need to know what kind of `StreamConsumer<Event>` is used:

```java
// either a ListEventConsumer or a FunctionalConsumer
StreamConsumer<Event> streamConsumer = // ...
Stream<Event> events = // ...

processEvents(streamConsumer, events);
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a functional way to first collect the elements of a stream and then immediately pass the collection to a consumer?

Just call the [`Consumer.accept(T t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) method directly:

```java
Stream<Event> stream = ...
Consumer<List<Event>> consumer = ...

consumer.accept(stream.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```